# React Expo web Production build includes native code as well

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, expo, webpack-production

I have a app created with expo and it contains Web and Native code and uses expo-webpack for generating the builds.

It has the below folder structure

```
->index.tsx
->screens
 |
 ->native
   |
   ->dashboard.tsx
 -web
   |
   ->dashboard.web.tsx
```

I'm using `npx expo export:web` command to create the web build. I have platform specific code written throughout the project.

My **index.tsx** file contains logic something like this

```
if (Platform.OS === 'web')
   return 'WebDashboard Component'
else
   return 'NativeDashboard Component';
```

My issue here is when I run the build command `npx expo export:web` I'm getting both WebDashboard code as well as NativeDashboard code in the final JS file post build, but I want only WebDashboard component to be present in the build file when I run the web build.

**Expo version: 49**

I want to reduce the final build file size by doing this as my current codebase is large.

Any suggestions would be helpful.